# backslash not last character on line

Tags: tcsh

I cannot run simple regular expression commands in a Linux lab. Because I do not understand the root of the problem, I can only provide command-line examples. The following two examples work:

```
% fgrep -h TestVar */config_file.txt
% sed -n /TestVar/p */config_file.txt
```

However the following two examples do not work:

```
% awk '/TestVar/ { print }' */config_file.txt
% perl -ne 'if (/TestVar/) { print }' */config_file.txt
```

Both errors indicate a backslash in the wrong place. Specifically, the very simple AWK command outputs the following:

```
awk: ^ backslash not last character on line
```

If I simplify the AWK command further, it will work as follows:

```
% awk /TestVar/ */config_file.txt
```

If I temporarily switch my login shell from TCSH (the default) to BASH, all the commands work. Last, if I run the AWK or PERL commands on a single file, the REGEX command also works in the original TCSH shell.

The simple example script is something I would never use in my day-to-day operations. I am typically parsing through or editing multiple files using much more complex REGEX commands. The issue is I have been unable to get any variation of my day-to-day REGEX commands to work in AWK or PERL, using the lab default TCSH shell. My REGEX commands work in all other labs, which also use TCSH. So there must be something specific to this lab environment that is causing the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Last, if I run the AWK or PERL commands on a single file, the REGEX command also works in the original TCSH shell.`. Does this file perhaps start with a `#!/bin/bash`? Because then you are not running the commands in tcsh.

Comment: Thinking along those lines, I simplified the input files further. I have just two text files, and each is just one line of very simple ASCII. The second file is just the string "TestVar". The error printed is the following:

awk: \/\T\e\s\t\V\a\r\/\ \{\ \p\r\i\n\t\ \}
awk: ^ backslash not last character on line

Comment: I don't understand. Where is there a backslash in your code? Both commands work for me.